# Why does this constexpr code cause GCC to eat all my RAM?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, metaprogramming, constexpr

The following program will call *fun* 2 ^ (MAXD + 1) times. The maximum recursion depth should never go above MAXD, though (if my thinking is correct). Thus it may take some time to compile, but it should not eat my RAM.

```
#include<iostream>

const int MAXD = 20;

constexpr int fun(int x, int depth=0){
  return depth == MAXD ? x : fun(fun(x + 1, depth + 1) + 1, depth + 1);
}

int main(){
  constexpr int i = fun(1);
  std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

The problem is that eating my RAM is exactly what it does. When I turn MAXD up to 30, my laptop starts to swap after GCC 4.7.2 quickly allocates 3 gb or so. I have not yet tried it with clang 3.1, as I don't have access to it right now.

My only guess is that this has something to do with GCC trying to be too clever and memoize the function calls, like it does with templates. If this is so, does it not seem strange that they don't have a limit on how much memoization they do, like the size of a MRU cache table or something? I have not found a switch to disable it.

Why would I do this?
I am toying with the idea of making an advanced compile time library, like genetic programming or something. Since the compilers do not have compile time tail call optimization, I am worried that anything that loops will need recursion and (even if I turn up the maximum recursion depth parameter, which seems slightly ugly to require) will quickly allocate all my RAM and fill it with pointless stack frames. Thus I came up with the above solution for getting arbitrarily many function calls without a deep stack. Such a function could be used for folding/looping or trampolining.

EDIT:
Now I have tried it in clang 3.1, and it will not leak memory at all, no matter how long I make it work (i.e how high I make MAXD). CPU usage is almost 100% and memory usage is almost 0%, just like expected. Perhaps this is just a bug in GCC then.

Comment: I have confirmed that the stack never goes beyond MAXD (as intended), by running the function runtime and observing that while I can make it run for a long time, it uses no RAM at all.

Comment: May be you should report this as recommended in http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/ ?

Comment: @osgx It isn't really a bug, though, is it? According to the standard I suppose they can do what they like to my RAM. Also, I would like someone who knows what they're doing (you know who you are ;) telling me what the reason is.

Comment: OK, now I have tested it on clang 3.1. Clang produces the "correct" behaviour and does not consume RAM. Seems it is a bug or misfeature with GCC.

Comment: OK, I have reported it as a bug: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55442

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the definitive document regarding constexpr, but it's the primary doc linked to from the [gcc constexpr wiki.](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Constexpr)

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2235.pdf

... and it says...

> We (still) prohibit recursion in all its form in constant expressions.
> That is not strictly necessary because an implementation limit on
> recursion depth in constant expression evaluation would save us from
> the possibility of the compiler recursing forever. However, until we
> see a convincing use case for recursion, we don’t propose to allow it.

So, I expect you're bumping up against language boundary and the way that gcc has chosen to implement constexpr (maybe attempting to generate the entire function inline, then evaluating/executing it)

Comment: That doc is too old, I think. The standard does not prohibit recursion, but suggests a default limit on 512 recursions, something both gcc and clang respects, but allow the user to override. You may be right that the issue is not memoization (though I know that gcc does that to constexprs) but that it expands the code inline.

Comment: @Gurgeh  - Yes - It seems to be a common problem with ISO standards that the web is scattered with every possible document except the actual standard itself :-) Is the recommended limit on the "number of recursions" or the recursion depth? as in your case the depth is 20, but the "number of recursions" could be considered to be 2^MAXD-1 as you say...

Comment: Definitely recursion depth. A simple recursion (substitute the inner fun(...) for x and increase MAXD) of deeper than 512 will make the compiler swear at you. A shallower will not.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is in your comment "by running the function runtime and observing that while I can make it run for a long time", which is caused by your inner most recursive call to fun(x + 1, depth + 1).

When you changed it to a runtime function rather than a compile time function by removing constexpr and observed that it ran a long time that's an indicator that it is recursing very deeply.

When the function is executed by the compiler it has to recurse deeply, but doesn't use the stack for recursion since it isn't actually generating and executing machine code.

Comment: of course it will. It returns just fine. Have you tried the code?

Comment: Recursing deeply is not the only method by which something can run for a long time. It can also branch broadly, which is what my code does.

Comment: Your code does not branch broadly.  It only has one branch and it takes the same side of the branch on every recursion until it stops recursing.

Comment: You are _completely_ wrong with everything you have written. 1) Both gcc and clang has a recursion limit of 512 compile time, unless you set it otherwise. The compilation will fail with an error message if you break this limit. Thus I know that the code does not recurse below 512. 2) The depth parameter should make it clear just by inspecting the code that the recursion does not go below MAXD.

Comment: 3) It does recurse "broadly". Imagine fun without the inner fun. That will result in MAXD calls, as it simply loops to the bottom. Sort of a linked list. The added inner fun means that on each step to MAXD, a subtree will be spawned off, which will in turn produce subtrees as it proceeds to MAXD. It will produce a binary tree of sorts. The output confirms this. 4) the compiled code will also use the stack for recursion, unless an optimization switch is used, which does the TCO. 5) clang does not exhibit this behaviour, which suggests it is a memoization problem with GCC.